# Unity rotation calculation

Tags: unity-game-engine, calculator, quaternions

```
    //RAYCAST
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    if(Physics.Raycast(impact.position, bloom, out hit, 1000f, canBeShot))
    {
        GameObject newBulletHole = Instantiate(bulletHolePrefab, hit.point + hit.normal * 0.001f, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        newBulletHole.transform.LookAt(hit.point + hit.normal);
        Destroy(newBulletHole, 5f);
    }

    //Bullet
    bulletSpawnPoint = GameObject.Find("BulletSpawn").transform;

    var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawnPoint.position, **bulletSpawnPoint.rotation**);
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bulletSpawnPoint.forward * loadout[currentIndex].bulletSpeed;
```

I need to get the perfect "bulletSpawnPoint.rotation" depending of my bullet hole created by the raycast hit. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dmXN.png)

Comment: Are you trying to get the gun to aim at the newBulletHole? What do you want "bulletSpawnPoint.rotation" to represent?

Comment: I currently have my ball which spawns at a specific location and which goes straight but this creates a shift with my Bullethole which starts where I aim and I would therefore like to align the two by finding the orientation to give my ball for which land in the bullet hole

Comment: bulletSpawnPoint.rotation is the value to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to spawn the bullet and then use Rigitbody to move it to the newBulletHole gameobject.

Easy way would be to store position of the bullet hole and then pass it into LookAt method of the bullet Transform before adding velocity.

A bit more advanced way (and this is what you are asking in your question, afaik): calculate the direction vector (`bulletSpawnPoint.transform.position - newBulletHole.transform.position`) and then get Quaternion (i.e. rotation) with [LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

Comment: Thanks you very much im gonna try that ^^